# XStream custom attribute for String field Java

Tags: java, rss, xstream

I'm working on RSS Feed using XStream library and I have following model (simplified for example purpose)

```
public class Item {
private String title;
private String link;
private String guid; }
```

And it works fine, it generates the part of the XML I need. The problem though is that I need to add custom attribute for guid ("isPermaLink") and I can't find any solution for that.

So the XML I need would be:

```
<item>
<title>Test</title>
<link>www.example.com/abc</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">www.example.com/abc</guid>
</item>
```

I know I can make attribute by using

```
@XStreamAsAttribute
```

So I tried to add another class for GUID

```
public class Guid {
    private String value = "http://example.com/abc";
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private boolean isPermaLink = true;
}
```

and point to that in my Item class but then the generated code contains GUID part like this:

```
<guid2 isPermaLink="true">
    <value>http://example.com/abc</value>
</guid2>
```

And I can't have this  element inside. The value needs to be inline.

The question is - how can I make the value inline OR how can I add attribute to String field

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for self answering but after spending some time on this topic I finally found an answer. Probably that can help someone so I'm posting it here.

Basically I think there is no default way of doing that. I went through all the tutorials on XStream and also looked at every single annotation available from XStream.

Finally I did manage to do a workaround that works. Basically in order to add an attribute to String (for example) you can use custom Converter and add an attribute there.
So on my guid field I'm using *XStreamConverter* to choose my converter:

```
@XStreamConverter(value = GuidConverter.class)
private String guid;
```

And the converter itself:

```
public class GuidConverter implements Converter{

    @Override
    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return String.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void marshal(Object source, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext context) {
        String value = (String) source;
        writer.addAttribute("isPermaLink", "false");
        writer.setValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader reader, UnmarshallingContext context) {
        //TODO if you need - I don't because I'm only marshalling in my scenario
        return null;
    }
}
```

This a shame that there is no "out of box" solution for that because if you had more String on which you wanted attribute or you wanted make these attributes values dynamic then... well the solution is not going to work for you.
In my case it worked because I always need same value (isPermaLink="false") but in most cases that's not going to be enough.

Perhaps someone has better idea to do that